# Abruptly closing a Ktor connection

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I want to close an `ApplicationCall` abruptly without sending a response back to the client to simulate a fault.

I cannot figure out how to do it since Ktor hides all the lower-level stuff from me.

I would like to do something like:

```kotlin
call.response.close() // ?
        
call.respondText { "This will not be received by the client because the connection has been closed" }
```

Can I do this without writing a custom `Plugin`?

Comment: What do you mean by closing abruptly an `ApplicationCall`?

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/http-the-definitive/1565925092/ch04s07.html A server should be able to close the underlying TCP connection at any time. I would like to cause an unexpected connection close exception for the client connecting to my Ktor server application.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is impossible.

Comment: Can I achieve this using a custom Plugin or is it completely against Ktor design?

Comment: No. That's about the capability to do it, not design.